# The limit of product $\prod_{x=2}^k(1-x^{-2})$ as $k\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinite-product

For some reason Wolfram is saying that as $k$ tends to infinity, $\prod_{x=2}^k(1-x^{-2})$ tends to zero, but my book is claiming that this product is never less than one half. Which is true, and why? I can't seem to make any ground into this.

Comment: Burn your books and worship Wolfram :-)

Comment: Could you give us link to what you ran on wolfram? did you start x from 2 or from 1???

Comment: @Arashium I think you are spot on. For me W|A evaluates just fine to 1/2.

Comment: Oh, okay I just made a stupid mistake

Comment: A very stupid mistake

Comment: Ignore this post, I forgot to NOT start the sum at 1

Comment: So of course it spat out zero

Comment: Of course it will be a half...how on earth did I miss that...

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite $1- x^{-2} = (x^2 - 1)x^{-2}= (x - 1)(x+1)x^{-2}$ and cancel.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{x=2}^k\frac{x-1}x\frac{x+1}x
&=\frac12\overbrace{\boxed{\displaystyle\frac32\cdot\frac23}\boxed{\displaystyle\frac43\cdot\frac34}\frac54\cdots\frac{k-2}{k-1}\boxed{\displaystyle\frac{k}{k-1}\cdot\frac{k-1}k}}^{\text{cancels to $1$}}\frac{k+1}k\\
&=\frac{k+1}{2k}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This just makes quids answer a bit more explicit

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I understood at his comment though so it's okay :P